# Suggest a Data Structure To Manage 2 Sets

Tags: data-structures, trees, sets

I was given the following problem which really baffled me, and I would like some guidance in solving it.

I want to make a data-structure which represents two sets $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so that I can Insert an element to a set of my choosing in $O(\log n)$ (where $n$ is the number of elements existing in both sets).

However, it is also required to be able to find in $O(1)$ some $x \in A\cup B$ such that the amount of elements in $A$ lesser than $x$, equates to the number of elements in $B$ greater than $x$, if exists:

$$\left | \left \{ y\in A: y<x \right \} \right | = \left | \left \{ y\in B: y>x \right \} \right |$$

Now the obvious direction is to use balanced trees (say AVL). I can use the same tree for both sets or separate to 2 different trees. I also presume I should store more data in the nodes, However I'm not sure which. I thought about storing the number of elements smaller and greater but that would make the Insert method $O(n)$, since I have to update many nodes in the respective tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right approach to attach "more data" to a balanced search tree.

For all $x\in A\cup B$, let $$d(x)=\left | \left \{ y\in A: y<x \right \} \right | - \left | \left \{ y\in B: y>x \right \} \right |,$$ which is an **increasing** function on $x$.

---

For simplicity, let us assume all elements are distinct first. We can use a balanced search tree $T$ to store all elements in $A$ and $B$, keeping track of whether each element comes from $A$ or $B$.

- We will also store $(x_\ell, \delta_\ell)$ , where $x_\ell$ is the largest element $x$ in $T$ such that $d(x)\le0$ and where $\delta_\ell=d(x_\ell)$.
- We will also store $(x_r, \delta_r)$ , where $x_r$ is the smallest element $x$ in $T$ such that $d(x)\ge0$ and where $\delta_r=d(x_r)$.

Either pair might not exist. However, at least one pair must be available, which is enough to identify the wanted $x\in A\cup B$, i.e., $d(x)=0$, if exists.

---

Suppose $v$ will be inserted into $T$. Here is a sketch of what to do to maintain the data structure. The idea is simply to move $x_\ell$ or $x_r$ to its neighbor one or two times.  Several obvious boundary cases such as when $d(x)>0$ for all $x$ in $T$ before or after $v$  is inserted have been skipped.

1. Insert $v$.
2. Update $(x_\ell, \delta_\ell)$ as the following.

   1. Do the following.

      - find $x_{-1}$, the predecessor of $x_\ell$. Compute $d(x_{-1})$.
      - find $x_{-2}$, the predecessor of $x_{-1}$. Compute $d(x_{-2})$.
      - find $x_{1}$, the successor of $x_\ell$. Compute $d(x_1)$.
      - find $x_{2}$, the successor of $x_1$. Compute $d(x_2)$.
   2. Let $x_{\text{new}}$ be the largest element $x$ among $x_{-2}, x_{-1}, x_\ell, x_{1}, x_{2}$ such that $d(x)\le0$. Update $(x_\ell, \delta_\ell)$ to $(x_{\text{new}}, d(x_{\text{new}}))$
3. Update $(x_r, \delta_r)$ similarly, which should take $O(\log n)$ time as well.

Any kind of balanced search trees can be used as long as the insertion, finding the predecessor and finding the successor can be done in $O(\log n)$. In particular, we can use AVL tree or red-black tree.

- Step 1 takes $O(\log n)$ time.
- Each search for predecessor or successor in Step 2 takes $O(\log n)$ time. Each computation of $d(*)$ takes $O(1)$ time, as we know $d(x_\ell)$. For example, $d(x_{-1})=d(x_\ell)-\lambda_A(x_{-1})-\lambda_B(x_\ell)$, where $\lambda_A(x_{-1})$ is 1 if $x_{-1}\in A$ and 0 otherwise. $\lambda_B(x_{\ell})$ is 1 if $x_{\ell}\in B$ and 0 otherwise. Similarly, $d(x_1)=d(x_\ell)+\lambda_A(x_\ell)+\lambda_B(x_1)$. So step 2 takes $O(\log n)$ tims.
- Similarly, step 3 takes $O(\log n)$ time.

---

When there are duplicated elements in $A$ and $B$, the idea is similar but somewhat more complicated. A balanced search tree $T$ will store all distinct elements in $A$ and $B$. Each node will store

- a distinct element $x\in A\cup B$,
- how many time that element appears in $A$,
- and how many time that element appears in $B$.

The order of the node is determined by the order of that element. Attached to the whole $T$ are the two pairs $(x_\ell, \delta_\ell)$ and $(x_r, \delta_r)$ defined the same as above.

---

**Exercise 1.** Refine the algorithm so that at any point of time, only one of the pairs $(x_\ell, \delta_\ell)$ and $(x_r, \delta_r)$ is maintained.

**Exercise 2.** Refine the algorithm so that only 1 or 2 cases in step 2.1 are needed by considering $v<x_\ell$ or not, $v=x_{-1}$ or not, $v\in A$ or $v\in B$, etc.

**Exercise 3.** Consider using one balanced search tree for elements in $A$ and another one for elements in $B$ instead of using one for both of them. Will it work?

Comment: Thank you very much! Are you sure though I can compute the $d$s of the succesors and predecessors in $O(1)$ if at all? It seems impossible to update the $\delta$s at all.

Comment: $d(x_{-1})=d(x_\ell)-\lambda_A(x_{-1})-\lambda_B(x_\ell)$, where $\lambda_A(\cdot)$ is the characteristic function of $A$, i.e., $\lambda_A(u)=1 \Longleftrightarrow u\in A$. $\lambda_B(\cdot)$ is the characteristic function of $B$, i.e., $\lambda_B(u)=1 \Longleftrightarrow u\in B$. Similarly, $d(x_1)=d(x_\ell)+\lambda_A(x_\ell)+\lambda_B(x_1)$.

Comment: Silly me, I figured I need to update $\delta$ along the path down to the successor. Can't thank you enough!